# MongooseError: Query was already executed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I updated Mongoose to the latest version (6.0.1) and now I'm getting this error whenever `.findOne()` is executed:

```
MongooseError: Query was already executed: Streams.findOne({ i: 6 })
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (C:\Users\honza\ZiggerTestMaster\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:21:19)
    at C:\Users\honza\ZiggerTestMaster\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  originalStack: 'Error\n' +
    '    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (C:\\Users\\honza\\ZiggerTestMaster\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\wrapThunk.js:25:28)\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\honza\\ZiggerTestMaster\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:370:33\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)\n' +
    '    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)\n' +
    '    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)'
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
var visitorData = Visitor.find({});
    
app.get("/retrieve", function(req,res){
    visitorData.exec(function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.render("retrieve", { title:"View Visitor Data", records: data});
     });
});
```

It executes properly the first time I open the route but, whenever I refresh it, it throws the above error. Has been happening since Mongoose got the latest version.

Comment: Can you include some sample code the error refers to? It is executing a query object more than once. There's a few ways you can do this, probably using a callback as a promise

Comment: ```
Guild.findOne(
  {
    guildID: message.guild.id,
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      error.sendError(err);
      return;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Are you `await`ing it anywhere? Also you can edit the code in to the original question.

Comment: How should I await a callback?

Comment: You shouldn't when using a callback, that's just one of the ways this can happen. Some people `await Streams.findOne({ i: 6 }, cb)` which executes the query twice. You also might be generating the query someone using it multiple times.  If you can come up with a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code people may be able to help more

Comment: Had the same issue while using promise based approach. Appending .exec() to my call chain solved the problem, e.g. User.findOne({email}) -> User.findOne({email}).exec()
Docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Comment: Just avoid using first error call back and use async await method.

Answer (score 43):

Had the same issues, but the release notes on mongoose helped, I chained a `.clone()` method to the `.find()` method:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#duplicate-query-execution

> Mongoose no longer allows executing the same query object twice. If
> you do, you'll get a Query was already executed error. Executing the
> same query instance twice is typically indicative of mixing callbacks
> and promises, but if you need to execute the same query twice, you can
> call Query#clone() to clone the query and re-execute it.

So all you need to do is to add a `.clone()` method to the end of the mongoose method that needs to be called concurrently like below (I restructured your code a bit):

```
app.get("/retrieve", function (req, res) {
    Visitor.find({}, function (err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            res.render("retrieve", { title: "View Visitor Data", records: data });
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }).clone().catch(function(err){ console.log(err)})
});
```

Comment: But what if I use .find() in some function where I cannot say if it was already executed or not?

Answer (score 15):

wrap your query within async-await.

```
const visitorData = async() => { 
  return await Visitor.find({});
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Don't use the callback within the findOne, instead
use .then() , after the Query, like so

```
 Visitor.find({})
.then(function (err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            res.render("retrieve", { title: "View Visitor Data", records: data });
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

This should most likely work , otherwise use clone() if necessary , as stated by
[Avis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7625773/avis)

Answer (score 5):

The error predominantly arises because the same query is executed more than once, the most often cause being unknowingly using promise and callback at the same time, to avoid such mistakes this error is thrown.
To get rid of this error, stick to either promise or callback when executing this query method.
Use:

```
await Model.findOneAndUpdate(query,doc,options)
// (or) regular .then() .catch() syntax
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query)
.then(res=>...)
.catch(err=>...)
```

(OR)

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, doc, options, callback)
```

The same principle applies to similar methods like `findByIdAndUpdate`.

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose v6 does not allow duplicate queries.

> Mongoose no longer allows executing the same query object twice. If you do, you'll get a Query was already executed error. Executing the same query instance twice is typically indicative of mixing callbacks and promises, but if you need to execute the same query twice, you can call Query#clone() to clone the query and re-execute it. See gh-7398

[Duplicate Query Execution](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#duplicate-query-execution)

In my case, I assumed my Apollo Server resolver will wait for the promise to resolve and return the result, but that wasn't the case. So I had to add async/await to the mongoose query.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose no longer allows executing the same query object twice. If you do, you'll get a Query was already executed error. Executing the same query instance twice is typically indicative of mixing callbacks and promises, but if you need to execute the same query twice, you can call ".clone();" to clone the query and re-execute it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the details but mine and my co-workers problems got fixed by downgrading mongoose to 5.13.14

Answer (score 1):

```
// Mongoose 6.6.3
// Query.prototype.clone()
// Returns:
// «Query» copy
// Make a copy of this query so you can re-execute it.

// Example:`enter code here`
const q = Book.findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' });
await q.exec();
await q.exec(); 
// Throws an error because you can't execute a query 
twice

await q.clone().exec(); // Works
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was using find() for finding a record like this:

```
foo.find(a=> a.id === id) //It is wrong!
```

It should be:

```
foo.findById(id)
```

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question and not the reason for the described behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
schemaName.pre(/^findOneAnd/, async function (next) {
  this.r = await this.findOne().clone();
   console.log(this.r);
  next();
});

use this code ⬇ 

schemaName.pre(/^findOneAnd/, async function (next) {
  this.r = await this.clone().findOne();
   console.log(this.r);
  next();
});


or use npm i mongoose@5
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was writing `$push` two time. Check if are using wrong query.

Hope, this can resolve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

The newer version of Mongoose (version 6+) doesn't support executing the same query object twice. So, just downgrade to an older version, like version 5.13.15.

*Uninstall the current Mongoose package & then download the older version:*

***npm uninstall mongoose***

***npm i mongoose@5***

Hope, this can resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).