# Update a value inside array of objects, inside a document in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is what my collection looks like

[image]

Now suppose I have to update `count` of 2nd document whose `reportTypes.reasonId` is 300. I have access to `_id` as well as `reasonId` to update the `count`. I am using Mongoose to query things in my Node application.

What can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via arrayFilters:

```
db.collection.update(
   { 
    managerId:3 
   },
   {
    $inc:{"reportTypes.$[x].count":1} 
   },
   { 
   arrayFilters:[{"x.reasonId":300  }]
   }
  )
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LOgWqC4Shl3)

Explained:
Specify the matching document in the query part and create arrayFilter "x" matching the correct reportTYpes array subdocument , in the update part use the $inc operation to increment the count value in the example with 1

Comment: I am really thankful to you. thank you very much bro. Keep doing the great work.

Comment: I have another question if you could answer. Imagine in this collection only `reportTypes` is an empty array and i have to insert this document (`{ reasonId: ObjectId(2353...),  count: 0 }`) only if it doesn't exist in the `reportTypes` array, otherwise do nothing. So my quest is how can i find weather `reportTypes` contains an object with some `reasonId` and how to update `reportTypes` array based on this condition.

Comment: maybe something like this using $push: https://mongoplayground.net/p/0X0o8r57wIA

Comment: alternatively you can use update/agg.pipeline: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MXystkuhFzT

Comment: yeah bro it is 100% working. Thanks for helping me out. Could u please tell me, from where have you learned mongodb or is it only from practice?

Comment: There is free of charge trainings provided officially by mongodb they are the best to start with ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243470/discussion-between-shubham-maheshwari-and-r2d2).

Answer (score 0):

you should use dot notation and the $ update operator to do this:
(I'm assuming your collection is called Reason)

```js
var conditions = {
  '_id': '6244........',
  'reasonTypes.reasonId': 300
}
var update = {
  $inc: {
    'reasonTypes.$.count': 1
  }
};

Reason.update(conditions, update, function(err) {
  // Handle error here
})
```

You can find more on the operator here [mongo $ update operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: Yeah bro i have tried this sol. but it gives me { acknowledged: false } and its not updating in my collection. Also i want to increment count by 1 (based on it's previous value).

Comment: Okay so I updated the code snippet, try that instead

Comment: Thanks brother for giving your precious time. But it isn't working it is giving me this  [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945315/mongooseerror-query-was-already-executed). But yeah my problem is solved with arrayfilter. Thank again.