# MongooseError: Query was already executed in discord.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, mongoose-schema

```js
MongooseError: Query was already executed: anti-ping-log.findOne({ Guild: '443905850634010625' })
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (/home/container/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:21:19)
    at /home/container/node_modules/kareem/index.js:367:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  originalStack: 'Error\n' +
    '    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (/home/container/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:25:28)\n' +
    '    at /home/container/node_modules/kareem/index.js:367:25\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)'
}
```

Whenever my discordbot is an event triggered / command is running, the error comes, see above, below then the code of the bot
Can it be that it lies because I have it twice in the code? I would send my entire code, but it goes over 300 lines, and that's a bit too long
But what you see should be sufficient

```js
antiPingSchema.findOne(guild, async(err, data) => {
    if(data){
        const member =  message.mentions.members.first()
        if(member){
            if(data.Member.includes(member.id)){
                antiPingRoleSchema.findOne(guild, async(err, data3) =>{
                    if(data3){
                        antipingtext.findOne(guildtext, async(err, data4) =>{
                            if(data4){
                                
                            }else if(!data4){

                            }
                        })
                        antipinglogchannel.findOne(guild, async(err, data2)=>{
                            if(data2){
                                
                            }else if(!data2){
                                return;
                            }
                        })
                    }else if(!data3){
                        antipinglogchannel.findOne(guild, async(err, data2)=>{
                            if(data2){
                                
                            }else if(!data2){
                                return;
                            }
                        })
                        antipingtext.findOne(guildtext, async(err, data4) =>{
                            if(data4){
                               
                            }else if(!data4){
                                
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        
        }else if(!data){
            return;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: _"Can it be that it lies because I have it twice in the code?"_ Yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseError: Query was already executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945315/mongooseerror-query-was-already-executed)