# Fetch data from mongo db from a function in one nodejs file and return it to another nodejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fetch

So, I want a function in dbAction.js to get data from mongoDB(mongoose). After getting the data I want to return it to app.js. But every time i run it I get `undefined`

```js
//in dbActionon.js

const db = require('./dbconnect') // This contains the mongoose connect and schema

 function getData() {
    let data;
         db.users.find(function (err, urls) {
            if (err) {
                data = "error"
            } else {
                data= urls
            }
        })
        return (data)
    }
exports.getData = getData
```

Code in app.js

```js
const dbAction = require('./dbAction')

function retrieve(){
  let data = dbAction.getData() 
  console.log(data)
}
```

I tried the code mentioned above and I expect help and code for how i can fix this issue.

Comment: `getData` should be `async` and you should `await` the results of the `find()`

Comment: I agree with the answer added above. Additionaly I would say becasue async/await is missing and db.users.find() returns Promise (I supose). Event loop of JS does not wait for resolving Promise and program is continued - so that's why data is 'undefined'. I would suggest to read about Event Loop in JS/Node.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, when I await the results of find. It says `MongooseError: Query was already executed`

Comment: You can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945315/mongooseerror-query-was-already-executed